# Safe to store Oauth2 access/refresh tokens in Shared Preferences in Android?

Tags: android, security, sharedpreferences, oauth-2.0

I know that I can set the values to be 'MODE_PRIVATE' and only my application/userId will be able to access them, however, is there any way for the user to access these at any point?  So is it 'safe' to store these in Shared Preferences, or is there a better place?

Furthermore, if I later decide to expose some preferences for setting by the user, would I be able to hide these values?

Thank you.

Edit: I know about Internal Storage as well, but am wondering if I can achieve something simpler with Shared Preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shared Preferences are just a plain-text XML file stored in the application's data folder. This is not a secure location, by any means. It's quite easy to view these files and extract the tokens. You can still use the Shared Preferences but you need to encrypt the information you are storing. As for "Internal Storage", those share the same location with the "Shared Preferences", so they're still easy to view.

Your unencrypted data is safe from OTHER applications running in the phone, but not from malicious users.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you store access tokens in the secure location on the device, you should think it can be revealed. That's why you shouldn't have client secret in your mobile application code.
For access tokens, you can try to keep them secure, but you can't make it 100% secure. So you shouldn't get unnecessary scopes or unnecessarily long lifetime tokens.

ps.
In general, mobile device uses "response_type=token (implicit grant)" and it shouldn't get refresh tokens. It depends on the authentication server's policy though..

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The oauth2 protocol we are using requires the use of refresh tokens as well as the typical access tokens.  The problem is we need to store them *somewhere* on the device, since it needs to be persistent across sessions and the app cannot store them.

Comment: OAuth2 spec requires mobile devices (all clients which can't have client secret) NOT to use refresh tokens. If the OAuth2 server you use requires it, it means the server isn't supporting such clients.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this?  I am looking at: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-15#section-4.4 and it says the refresh_token is optional

Comment: Implicit Grant is the flow for clients which can't have client secret. http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-15#section-4.2

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show some preferences to the user you won't have to worry about these showing up.  I think shared_preferences would probably be the 'safest' place to store these things. Unless the user has a rooted phone and they give a malicious app root permission to go read your data files then there is nothing to worry about as far as I know. Although I am looking forward to others responses. starred!